# How to pan a shapefile in QGIS to change its center?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I might be missing domain-specific vocabulary (please feel free to edit with it), but what I want to do is: getting a worldwide shapefile, like this one below (which is the [TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoEq7.png) shapefile)

[image]

And pan/change its center so it would look something like this (I made this in photoshop)
[image]

How can I achieve this in QGIS?

My final goal is actually to be able to have this "panned view" world map without the Russian nib on the left in R Leaflet, so if with the same result can be achieved in Leaflet without touching the shapefile, that is also something that would work

Comment: For Leaflet I've experimented with "setView", but that only seem to work with tiles, and I need this to work with Polygons

Comment: I guess you'd have to create a custom projection which places everything west of 170 west east of 180 east.

Comment: I'm not sure how should I do that but preserve everything else exactly the same with the default projection from R Leaflet